# After AccountManager..getAuthToken, how to send that token to its provider to authenticate something?

Tags: twitter-oauth, google-oauth, facebook-oauth, android-account

We're writing an app with an Android view and a website. Our app needs to associate some data with Facebook, Google, or Twitter (call them 'FGT'), and then hit the associated service to return `true` if that data is authenticated. The control flow is...

1. Android generates some data
2. User selects an FG or T account
3. getAuthToken
4. upload the data+token, via HTTPS POST, to our website
5. Our website (in Django, not that it matters) sends the Auth Token to FGT
6. FGT returns `true` if it likes that token, and `false` if it doesn't

The goal is preventing an attacker from concocting data and throwing it at our site with `curl`. And we /don't/ need to upload the data all the way to F, G, or T. We don't need to go all the way to a Hybrid App, where our webservice authenticates itself to F, G, or T, and then uses F, G, or T's API to post, e-mail, or tweet in the user's name.

There's obviously a simple answer for this out there somewhere; hopefully just three URIs, one each for F, G, or T, into which I can insert the Auth Token. That's why I would prefer NOT to download and install the SDK for each of Facebook, Google, and Twitter, and then write tons of service-specific code for each case. That would clutter up the code, and leave me screwed when the client requests Tumblr or MSN.

(A related question: What's the second parameter of `getAuthToken()`? "ah"? "mail"?)

So, while I continue to read books, source code, and SO posts showing how to do hard things the hard way, can someone tip me off how to do an easy thing the easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread "[validating Android's authToken on third party server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844694/validating-androids-authtoken-on-third-party-server)" answered the sub-question "what simple URI to hit to test a token?"

The magic uri, for Google, is: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/tokeninfo?access_token=%token_here%

The next question is How to thump an Access Token out of getAuthToken. The scope there should be the minimum possible to show a user really lives here:

```
String SCOPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
am.getAuthToken(a, SCOPE, false, this, null);
```

My `this` class implements `AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>` and provides the method `run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result)`. That, per documentation such as "[Android AccountManagerFuture getResult gives IOEXcelption when trying to get authorization token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768650/android-accountmanagerfuture-getresult-gives-ioexcelption-when-trying-to-get-aut)", might call `startActivity()` to challenge the user to authorize this activity, or it might use a token that's already stored in the AccountManager. (And note that implementing a class just to call-back yourself is pernicious, especially if the target method's named merely `run()`, so do as I say not as I do, kids!)

The resulting token is 52 bytes long, beginning with 'ya29.', so it's _ probably _ an access_token, not 331 characters, which is probably an id_token.

The resulting token is not bound to any specific channel (where "channel" is one unique set of client, server, and scope). So, from a simple curl, I can hit that `/tokeninfo` URI with it, and get this (scrubbed) JSONic wisdom:

```
{
  "issued_to" : "442575845966-mde4be7eingpb5pntfs839jipsetro6s.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "audience" : "424242424242-mde4ab7defghi5jklmn839opqrstuv6s.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "user_id" : "424242424242424242424",
  "scope" : "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
  "expires_in" : 2272
}
```

And so this answer would have formed, for me, the missing link between all the other documentation I was trying to read. Aaand now I need to do it all again for Facebook & Twitter...

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple URL. 
Each authtoken is granted against a scope. Each scope allows the authtoken to do certain things. If you try to do something that the scopes permit, that thing will fail or succeed based on the validity of the authtoken.

The simplest scope to request is probably 'email'.

If you go to the Oauth2 Playground at https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ you can experiment with scopes and calls to get one that suits you. You'll be able to see the URLs that you then need to replicate in your app.

Comment: The oauthplayground scope turned out to be just the lowly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile . Tx. I will presently write up how to use that to get an access_token. (I was formerly getting an id_token, which is channel-specific.)